# The right statistical method to measure a complex synergy

Tags: modeling, interaction, mediation

In order to measure multidimensional effects, it can be common to compute a score, as a combination of unidimensional factors.

For instance, one could compute a score `X` as the sum of concentrations of toxics (maybe weighted), or as an "anthropometric" score like `BMI+height+age+number of fingers` (let's call these score components `Ci`) and test `X` as a predictor of some outcome `Y`, like the incidence of some disease. I will call confounding variable `Z` but in fact they will be plural.

I'd like to test the hypothesis that there is a synergy, a "cocktail" effect in the association of my components.

Thus, the effect of the sum (the score) is expected to be greater than the sum of the effects (the components). In the toxics example, the hypothesis would be that the effect of simultaneous exposure to several toxics on some outcome is greater than the sum of the effect of each toxic on this outcome.

### First approach : simple model

My first approach was to model `Y` depending on `X` adjusted on `Ci` and some confounding variable Z:

```
Y ~ X + C1 + C2 + C3 + Z
```

If all `Ci` are fixed, the remaining effect on `X` should be the added effect, the "cocktail". A simple LRT on the model with and without `X` should give a handleable result. The obvious problem is the huge colinearity between `X` and all `Ci`.

### Second approach : interactions

My second approach was to compute my score `X` as list of scores `X'i`minus each of its components `Ci`. Thus, if `X = sum(C1+C2+...+Cn`, then `Xi = X - Ci`.

I then model `Y` depending on `X'i` interacting with `Ci`, and still adjusted confounding variable Z:

```
Y ~ X'1 * C1 + Z
...
Y ~ X'n * Cn + Z
```

Interactions are often used as the measure of synergy. In this case however, I'm afraid that measuring all synergies separately cannot relate the complex synergy between all my components.

Another possibility would be to make a general model with all interaction terms:

```
Y ~ X*C1*C2*...*Cn + Z
```

But since I actually have 13 components in my score, making such a model would certainly make my computer burn. And even if I manage to compute it, interaction terms of order >=3 are really hard to interpret and I have no clue on how I'd be supposed to interpret the results.

### Third approach : multiple mediation

My third approach was to use a multiple mediation model (like the [fig. 1 here](https://openresearchsoftware.metajnl.com/articles/10.5334/jors.160/)). If I model the action of `X` on the outcome as mediated by all `Ci` (still with other adjusments), my direct effect (bottom arrow) should be the "cocktail" effect. Unfortunately, I have too little experience with SEM and mediation analysis to validate this design.

**Is one of these designs correct to measure a synergy ?**

**Else, which kind of analysis would permit such a measure ?**

Any practical (best if not theorical) scientific reference or example is greatly welcomed.

Comment: Your goal isn't quite clear - are you trying to perform controlled statistical inference on which interaction effects exist (i.e. you have some hypothesis or set of hypothesis coming in), or are you trying to "mine" which interaction effects may exist?

Comment: I tried to clarify my hypothesis a bit, is it better ? This is definitely not data-mining, but I'd think it was pretty clear. Please tell me if it's still not.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that there are several questions / constraints. You seem to simultaneously want to understand *if any* interaction effects exist, while also wanting to understand *which* interaction effects exist. All while having no hypothesis for what these interaction effects may be or what degree they are.

Comment: The *which interaction* doesn't really matter. I want to know if there is a *global* interaction. Without the colinearity problem in my first approach, this would be testing that the coefficient for the score `X` is not null after adjusting for every component `Ci` and for `Z`. How could I phrase this better ?